# How to redirect to a page by checking query param in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a url such as exampleurl.com/#login/1234.

If I use exampleurl.com/#login it will check for query param in app.js and if param is not there it will redirect to some other page such as exampleurl.com/#error

I am using Angularjs and Angular router.

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#/login/11">Moby</a> |
<a href="#/login/22">Gatsby</a> |
<script src="../js/angular-route.js"></script>  //maybe you need route the module in angular 1.3.9
// this is app route config
var app = angular.module('routeApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
            .when('/login/:id', {
                templateUrl: 'yourTemp.html',
                controller: 'yourCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({templateUrl: '404.html'});
});
```